# Acces to a model relation in an Eloquent Query

Tags: laravel

I try to make a particular query but i'm not sure how to achieve this , i would like to access to **saison** table

```
{{ \App\Licencies::where(['structure_id' => Auth::user()->structure->id])->where(['saison_id->dt_fin' ,  '<' , \Carbon\Carbon::now()])->count() }}
```

here the saison() relation in my model , that i can access very well

```
$licencie->saison->dt_fin < \Carbon\Carbon::now()
```

someone knows to right query ? thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Do you want to filter the licenses where the seasons have already ended? Please let uw know what the expected result is!

Comment: exactly ! i would like to display the licence where the saison is ended . i have saison_id in my licencies "table" and saisons table with dt_deb and dt_fin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the explanation in the comment.

In the Laraval documentation there is the following example:

```
// Retrieve all posts with at least one comment containing words like foo%
$posts = Post::whereHas('comments', function ($query) {
    $query->where('content', 'like', 'foo%');
})->get();
```

Which can easily be transformed for your purpose:

```
// Retrieve all licencies where the saison has a dt_fin before now
$licencies = \App\Licencies::whereHas('saison', function ($query) {
    $query->where('dt_fin', '<', \Carbon\Carbon::now());
})->get();
```

If it still returns errors, let us know! (kinda hard to test without carbin and a structure that is equal to yours)

Comment: AND IT'S WORK ! thanks so much i didn't knows that i could do a WhereHas condition like this ! really easy to understand , thanks a lot !!!!! for your help , i wish you a good day